# Calculating line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The curve $\gamma$ is parameterized by:

$t \rightarrow(\cos t, \sin t), t \in [0,2\pi]$

I want to calculate the following integrals and I am supposed to explain what "type" of integral each one is.

1)$\space$$\space$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}||d \vec{x}||$; $\space$
 2)$\space$$\space$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}\vec{x}||d \vec{x}||$; $\space$ 
 3)$\space$$\space$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||^2}\vec{x} d\vec{x}$; $\space$
 4)$\space$$\space$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}\vec{x}ds$; $\space$
 5)$\space$$\space$$\oint_{\gamma} x_1x_2^2dx_1+x_1^2x_2dx_2$

What is "type" referring to here? Is this question asking if I have a vector or scalar line integral?

Here is what I have tried so far:

$||\vec{x}(t)||=\sqrt{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}=1$

$\frac{d\vec{x}(t)}{dt}=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(t) \\ \cos(t) \end{pmatrix}$

$\space$

$1) \space \space \oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}||d \vec{x}||=\oint_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1}\cdot dt=2\pi$

2) $\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}\vec{x}||d \vec{x}||=\oint_{0}^{2\pi}1\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \end{pmatrix} dt$

I wasn't sure how to integrate vectors but I looked it up and it seems to be:

$\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \cos t \space \space dt+\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \sin t \space \space dt$

This doesn't make much sense because the integral turns out to be $-2$. How can an area be negative?

3)$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||^2}\vec{x} d\vec{x}=\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \begin{pmatrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -\sin t \\ \cos t \end{pmatrix} \space dt=0$

4) $\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}\vec{x}ds$=?

5) $\oint_{\gamma} x_1x_2^2dx_1+x_1^2x_2dx_2=?$

I am not sure about the last two integrals.

Maybe someone can give me a hint and check if what I have done so far makes any sense.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For 2, you have two line integrals; one for each scalar component of the 2-D vector.  Integrate the components separately.   Each integral is zero.

For 3, you have a tensor $\vec x d\vec x$ that has $4$ components.  They are

$$-\cos t \sin t$$

$$\cos^2t$$

$$-\sin^2t$$

$$\cos t \sin t$$

For 4, note that $ds=d\vec x/||d\vec x||=dt$ and ||\vec x||=1.  So, the integral reduces to

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (\hat x \cos t+\hat y \sin t)dt=0$$

For 5, use Green's Theorem.  If one chooses not to use Green's theorem, then one can retain the parameterization and write $dx_1=-\sin t dt$ and $dx_2 = \cos t dt$.  The integral of interest becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (-\cos t \sin^3 t +\cos^3 t \sin t)dt=0$$

Comment: How could I miss that. $(\sin(2\pi)-\sin(0))-(\cos(2\pi)-\cos(0))=0$ and not 2. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  And the integral in (5) is actually straightforward too.

Comment: Ah that also turns out to be zero. I am starting to sense a pattern here.... :D. The question also asks what type of integral 1-5 is. What is meant by "type"?

Comment: I am not sure what the author is asking with "type."  Your interpretation sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It always seems so easy after someone explains it.

Comment: So what I did for 3) is wrong?

Comment: The way that it was written, it appears that this is a tensor and has $4$ components.  Was there supposed to be a scalar product here? I didn't see the "dot."

Comment: No there was no dot in the question.

Comment: And if no dot is implied, then this is a tensor.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.